# Ordered persistence within a Propel transaction

Tags: php, mysql, propel, propel2

I'm trying to make use of a lifecycle callback in Propel, `postInsert`.  The issue that I'm running into is that there is a chicken/egg scenario due to the persistence ordering of INSERTs and database FK constraints.

In the callback, I need the current object/record to be persisted, which you would think would be the case by the time the `postInsert` method is executed.  However, that does not seems to be happening (I haven't dug into the Propel lib to confirm yet).  I'm not sure if this is a bug/otherwise, or the fact that it's in a Propel transaction and persistence is handled later in the lifecycle (surely hoping that's not the case).

Since this is a `postInsert` callback and it's not actually being persisted prior, I'm unable to force a `save()` at this point, as that results in a endless loop.

I'm running out of ideas, outside of refactoring all the code around this to handle it independently by forcing persistence.

Firstly, can someone confirm if persistence, within a transaction, should occur before a `postInsert`, thereby making an auto-incremented primary key value available?

If that's not the intended functionality, is there a way to instruct Propel on the order of INSERTs for which to respect within a given transaction?

Example code if the above isn't clear:

```
$con = Propel::getConnection()
$con->beginTransaction();
$foo = new \Foo();
$foo->save();
$con->commit();
```

Foo Model

```
class Foo extends BaseFoo
{
    public function postInsert()
    {
        if (!$this->getId())
            throw new Exception("id is not available.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague to me. Could you perhaps give us some information on your database structure, the code in your postInsert() and the code you are using the save/persist the object?

Comment: Regarding persistence, propel handles saves, and that includes pre- and postSave methods, within a transaction. That means that for outside processes, depending on the replication mode you have set for MySQL, your new rows will not yet be visible. However, within the same transaction, you should have no issues.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case - no replication.  We weren't able to figure out why a `postInsert` wouldn't have an auto incremented value available.  Instead we created database triggers to solve this issue.  The issue still remains, however.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information and some code samples so we can check / reproduce the issue. I have no issues whatsoever with insert ids on propel, so it does seem to be something specific to your implementation.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do "with insert ids".  That works fine.  It has everything to do with the lifecycle callbacks, and most likely only within a transaction.  Unfortunately I'm not sure what other information would be helpful here.  We've solved the issue by not using propel for this and instead using triggers at the db level.

Comment: Then we're back at the start, your question is very vague / unclear. You will really need to provide some code samples if you want to get assistance. No one is going to be able to give any proper advice without more information.

Comment: @chocochaos added some code.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. I can run this exact code, and the id will be set in postInsert / postSave. If you check doInsert in the base class for your model, at the end of the method Propel gets the last insert id and then calls setId to store it in the model. There is no early return point in doInsert, any error would throw an exception. There are only three options I can think of: you're running an outdated / buggy revision of Propel, you have overridden the doInsert, or you are using a custom builder that does not generate proper doInsert logic.